# Redis - any way to trigger an event when a value is no longer being actively written to?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a use case where I'm streaming and processing live data into an Elasticache Redis cluster. In essence, I want to kick off an event when all events of a certain type have completed (i.e. the size of a value is no longer growing over the course of 60 seconds).

For example:

```
foo [event1]
foo [event1, event2]
foo [event1, event2]
foo [event1, event2] -> triggers some event if this key/value is constant for 60 seconds.
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that as part of all "changing" commands also set a key with a 60-second ttl. You can then subscribe to the expiration of that key using [redis keyspace notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications).

Comment: Quick followup - wouldn't the `EXPIRE` function remove that row entirely? I would need a way to get it instead of just losing it.

Comment: @Kris I would set a separate key with the TTL that maps to the one you're tracking. Like `foo_watch` or similar.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks : )