# Retrieve value from expired keys

Tags: redis

I have a use case where I'm aggregating until a TTL hits 0 on the key/value in Redis. As far as I can tell in the documentation, retrieval or a background job triggers all expired keys to be deleted immediately.

Is there anyway I can 'halt' that deletion and retrieve the value at the time of expiry? Or something similar to that effect?

My last question contains some context to my use case: [Redis - any way to trigger an event when a value is no longer being actively written to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59073206/redis-any-way-to-trigger-an-event-when-a-value-is-no-longer-being-actively-wri/59074440#59074440)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found an answer to my question. Every row would have a corresponding row with with the convention `expiry:{key}`.

```
uniqueEventHash: [value1, value2, value3] // no expiry
expiry:uniqueEventHash: {no value} // set TTL to 60
```

Now, whenever a new `value` for that `uniqueEventHash` arrives, I do two things. I append it onto the `uniqueEventHash` row with an `append`, and then I also subsequently reset the TTL on `expiry:uniqueEventHash` to 60.

When events for that `uniqueEventHash` stop arriving, the second `expiry:expiry:uniqueEventHash` is deleted and a notification is sent out to a subscriber to `EXPIRY` events. In the message is the key that expired, which in this case is `expiry:uniqueEventHash`.

I can then do the following:

```
// pseudo code
onExpiryEvent(message):     

    [type, key] = eventMessage.split(':');
    aggregatedValue = await getByKey(key);
    del(key);
```

Comment: Mind that it is possible to lose messages with PubSub, so a background process that scans for "dangling" hashes is still a good idea.

Comment: You mean a scan for keys containing TTL's that have already hit 0, but haven't trigger subsequent events?